# Best way to make a multiplayer game with both local and personal server?

Tags: objective-c, ios, architecture, multiplayer

I plan to make a multiplayer game (a quick turn-based card game), wich has to be playable :

- Solo against A.I.
- Locally (WiFi / Bluetooth) with or without A.I.
- On the internet, with waiting rooms and all, so I need a personal server

I plan to use Game Center.

Each part is ok on its own, I just can't figure how to mix everything...

For the local part (solo and p2p game), the server has to be on a device, but it has to be on a real server machine for the internet part ([Explanation image](http://tof.canardpc.com/view/f39a4c0f-519a-414d-a876-1ac67d0c68e6.jpg))... So, **do I have to code twice the server code with two different languages**? Argh!

If you have any advice, thank you in advance :)

Comment: I unintentionally deleted an answer... Sorry for the poster.
Anyway, I need to have an hosted server : logs, game control, and most importantly I need to get to 8 players at the same time.